# File Download - WinSock

Tags: c, winapi, winsock

After downloading an exe file from my server via WinSock in C. I get this error:

[image]

Here is the code I use to write the bytes read to the file:

```
while (recv(mySock, buf, FILEBUFFER, 0) > 0)
{
     WriteFile(hFile, buf, sizeof(buf), &bytes, NULL);
}
```

Here are the variable definitions used:

```
#define FILEBUFFER 2048

CHAR buf[2048]
```

Anyone know how I can fix this, or what the problem is?

Answer (score 3):

You're assuming `recv` returns the full buffer every time, but there's no guarantee (when simply testing `> 0`) that it returns any more than 1 byte. You need to use the result of `recv` as the amount of data to write to the file.

Comment: Oooh, so instead of `buf` in `WriteFile`, I do: `while (var1 = recv(mySock, buf, FILEBUFFER, 0) > 0){ WriteFile(hFile, var1, sizeof(var1), &bytes, NULL); }` ?

Comment: @AndrewPeters: `sizeof(var1)` ? Seriously? `buf` is still the buffer to write, `var1` is how much data there is in it.

Comment: Lol sorry, that was a quick 30 second response without thinking about wthat you said first. So `var1` would replace my `sizeof()`, if thats what you're saying? Because recv() returns the "quantity" or size of the bytes it reads for the current instance?

Comment: @AndrewPeters: yes. And of course, don't just blindly read from the connection until it fails, either.  If you don't know the size of the file ahead of time, you can't do adequate error checking to make sure you actually received the entire file.  So send/receive the file size first, then receive the actual file, and compare the read size to the actual size.  If they do not match, do not use the file.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the advice remy, I would give you a +1 if I could. But how would I retrieve just the content-length segment from the response?

Comment: Oh hold on now, I removed the check mark as, I did what you guys said, and I still received the same error message after opening the file.

Comment: Just a 'dumb' question, what is the architecture of you host machine, *i.e.* is it 32-bit or 64-bit.  And what architecture is the file you are downloading compiled for?  The error message you give, would lead me to think that you have a mismatch in architecture.

Comment: I tried both x64 & x86 files for this specific one I am trying to download. My host is x64.

Comment: another dumb question...what are the first four bytes of the file you downloaded?  ((BTW, this is running through all the 'silly' things I've seen people do, and the lack of information about what you are doing forces me to ask these questions))

Comment: ^^ yeah, all 'standard' TCP erorrs:(

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you are using plain winsock to download files, you need to construct the proper http requests and process the responses properly. When you get the response from the server, make sure you process the response instead of blindly writing it with the file.

Second, you should check the return value of `recv` to see how many bytes it received and write that amount instead.

Third, if you  just want to download a file without manually processing the requests and responses, you can use the `URLDownloadToFile` API or use the WinInet APIs.